# Video Conversion Tool in Debian 6?

Tags: linux, debian, video

Is there any video conversion software in debian 6 which supports all format?

Answer (score 2):

How about [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) should do what you want
http://www.debian-multimedia.org/dists/wheezy/main/binary-kfreebsd-i386/package/handbrake-cli.php